# SQL sorting by asc/ desc

Tags: mysql, sorting

How do i sort my data in sql in `asc or desc order`?

I am using :

```
ORDER BY DESC
```

but my data is not in order. The data for my codes are below :

```
AC1, AC2 ,AC3 ..., AC30,AC31
```

The sql sorts the data by the first letter and not the value of the data so my data is sorted like this

```
AC10, AC11, AC12, AC13 ... AC19
```

Next in line would be :

```
AC20, AC21, AC22, AC23
```

I would like my data to be sorted from the very first number `(AC1,AC2,AC3...)` and not `(AC1,AC10,AC11)`

Comment: Store the 'ac' separate from the digit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `order by` is working correctly.  Your expectation is wrong.  Strings are sorted alphabetically.

You can easily get what you want.  Assuming the column starts with two letters, you can do:

```
order by char_length(col) desc, col desc
```

If you want the default sort to work, then just pad the numbers . . . `AC01`, `AC02`, and so on.

Comment: Sorry what exactly is col? I'm new to sql and I have not learnt that. Would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: @Kris . . . Whatever column you want to sort by.  You don't specify it in the question.